# Meteor package (yogiben:admin) refuses to install, seems to be picking up wrong version from github?

Tags: github, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I'm using aldeed:autoform@5.  I also want to use yogiben's autoform-file, but I had trouble getting that to work with autoform@5 so I've used a fork by abdj:autoform-file.

Now I want to use yogiben:admin.  According to the discussion on github and the latest master (https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin/blob/master/package.js), yogiben:admin@1.1.0 uses `aldeed:autoform@4.2.2 || 5.0.0`.

So why do I get this error?

```
C:\Webdev\koolaid>meteor add yogiben:admin@1.1.0
 => Errors while adding packages:

While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint aldeed:autoform@4.2.2 is not satisfied by aldeed:autoform 5.1.2.
Constraints on package "aldeed:autoform":
* aldeed:autoform@5.0.2 <- abdj:autoform-file 0.2.0
* aldeed:autoform@4.2.2 <- yogiben:admin 1.1.0
```

Looks to me like Meteor is somehow picking up the wrong version from github? BTW I'm using Meteor WindowsPREVIEW@0.3.0.

**How do I get all these packages to play nice together?**

Comment: I would think that you'd want to just run "meteor add yogiben:admin" and let it handle providing aldeed:autoform to you since it is a listed dependency.  But it seems that Meteor's api.use method is grabbing the lowest acceptable version number.  That's odd.  I wonder if this is a Meteor bug.  These may be related: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4165, https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4170

Comment: Hi @Mark Leiber, yeah when I let meteor choose, it picks yogiben:admin@1.0.9 which I know definitely doesn't support AFv5. Weird...

Comment: Just posted a link to this SO from issue 4165